# React Native Making Changes and Updates After Publishing iOS App for TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Finally, I got my app uploaded to Testflight! This is a big stepping stone for me, however, what happens when you need to make a change? Is there a process that you need to do? I built my app again on XCode. Does it automatically update on the users' phones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For again pushing a new build,

1.Increment your build number in general tab on Xcode for project name(Very important).

2.Archive your project in product -> archive

3.Distribute the archived to testflight as you did before.

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: Thanks, also gotta mention that I can't have more than 1 build at the same time. I had to remove from the review before testing the updated build.

Comment: yes, you can only 1 build for the app, but theres a tweak. suppose you have 2 iphones, you can give 2 builds for testing